# Is it possible to change an emacs syntax table based on context?

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode, font-lock-mode

I'm working on improving an emacs major mode for [UnrealScript](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UnrealScriptReference.html).  One of the (many) quirks is that it allows syntax like this for specifying tooltips in the Unreal editor:

```
var() int MyEditorVar <Foo=Bar|Tooltip=My tooltip text isn't quoted>;
```

The angle brackets after the variable declaration denote a pipe-separated list of Key=Value metadata pairs, and the metadata is not quoted but can contain quote marks -- a pipe (`|`) or right angle bracket (`>`) denotes the end.

Is there a way I can get the emacs syntax table to recognize this context-dependent syntax in a useful way?  I'd like everything except for pipes and right angle brackets to be highlighted in some way inside of these variable metadata declarations, but otherwise retain their normal highlighting.

Right now, the single quote character is set up to be a quote delimiter (syntax designator `"`), so font-lock-mode interprets such a quote as starting a quoted string, which it's not in this very specific instance, so it mishighlights everything until it finds another supposedly matching single quote.

Comment: What major-mode are you using for this?

Comment: @Thomas: [This major mode](http://badbyteblues.blogspot.com/2010/12/unrealscript-mode-for-emacs-reloaded.html), with some modifications (extra keywords, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to setup a `syntax-propertize-function` which lets you apply different syntax designators to different characters in the buffer, depending on their context.

Grep for `syntax-propertize-function` in Emacs's lisp directory to see various examples (from simple to pretty complex ones).

You'll probably want to mark the "=" chars after your "Foo" and after your "Tooltip" as "generic string delimiter", then do the same with the corresponding terminating "|" and ">".  An alternative could be to mark the char before the ">" as a (closing) generic string delimiter, so that you can then mark the "<" and ">" as open&close parens.